# Can somebody tell if we can use Font awesome icons in @media print css? Does they work like on web?

Tags: css, font-awesome, print-css

I just simply want to know if we can use font awesome icons in printing media query, I mean does they will work like they do on browser or the will just get crashed. Someone please tell me.

Comment: Ehm, you don't have print preview capabilities?

Comment: Ah yes @MrLister, I did that and got my answer :) Thanks. It shows maximum icons only few were missing or having some rectangular shapes but thats Okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the **[Font Awesome Assets](http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip)** available in your project directory, yes but there were some issues regarding some icons showing as black circles/rectangles, but I don't have any fresh information about that.

As **[@Mr Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister)** said, you should try a Print-Preview version of Your website.

There is also a **[plugin for this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/printprint-preview/)** under Firefox.